# Get value of x from equation stored in string

Tags: c#, string, math, equation-solving

How can I get value of `x` from string equation using c#.

```
string eq = sin(x) = 5x-2""
eq = "x=(1/5)*(sin(x)+2)"
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: please format your code because it contains mistakes

Comment: Doesn't solving for `x` entail that `x` is either on the left or right hand side of your `=`? Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Try researching about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor quality question aside, what you want is either to create your expression **parser** which will then either **compile** or **interpret** the expression, OR you could use an open source library like NCalc:

http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

This is built to do this sort of thing.